# RequestMapping doesn't work when I use JDBC API dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

I'm currently learning spring boot and I want to create a rest api that reads from MySQL database. In my application, I put Spring Web dependency and JDBC API dependency. However, when I open localhost:8080 in my browser I don't see anything.

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/")
    public String getGreeting(){
        return "Hi there";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>live-elevation-backend</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>live-elevation-backend</name>
        <description>Backend layer for rack elevation</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Do you get an empty page? Can you try using `curl`? Is there something relevant in the log/console? Does it work without JDBC? What are the packages of `MainController` and your application class?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in your question, assuming the rest of your app has been configured correctly (e.g. a MySQL connector, DB credentials, etc.). What's in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @dan1st Yes that works when I only have Spring Web dependency. Also, when I go to the localhost in the browser it says that this page cannot be reached

Comment: @andrewJames I just shared my `pom.xml`

Comment: OK - thank you. When you use `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`, you need to provide [the JDBC connector for MySQL](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) (since that is the DB you want to use). And you have to provide the relevant connection details in your Spring properties file (URL/user/pass). But you should have been seeing errors/messages about this in the application's log/console (as noted by @dan1st) when you started your application.

Comment: @andrewJames Thank you for your response. Do you have a good resource where I can read about this

Comment: Take a look at [Accessing data with MySQL](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/). Look at the section describing the `application.properties` file. As for the JDBC driver, use the link I provided and add the relevant dependency to your `pom.xml` file. Which one you need depends on the version of MySQL you are using.  (Stack Overflow probably has eleventy-billion questions and answers covering these topics, also. But this info should get you going in the right direction.)